# List dependant/child sheets that call parent sheet by IMPORTRANGE()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to retrieve a list of all google sheets (children) that have ever established connection to a particular sheet (parent) by the IMPORTRANGE function. This function specifically asks a user to allow access to the parent sheet on first connection which leads me to hope this information is available somehow.
I am maintaining this relationship manually now but as the number of child sheets grow it would be helpful if the relationship can be read somehow with GAS/an API.
Any help to deal with this is very welcome :pray:

Comment: To clarify, you'd like to get the list of all the spreadsheet files that have the [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) function on them that use the primary spreadsheet that you're using. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Saddles, yes that's correct. Just mind you, they can be spread all over hundreds of shared drives so I can't crawl randomly through files. I need to be able to obtain that information that was initially created when the links were established by the users (as requested by the IMPORTRANGE() function).

Comment: Gotcha. I found similar discussions posted on multiple occasions in the [Google Docs Editors Help Community](https://support.google.com/docs/community), and unfortunately, this feature isn't available yet as per the answers on [Is it possible to see if another user is using importrange() on my sheet?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28277776), [How do I locating all spreadsheets that are using (IMPORTRANGE) from a specific sheet?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153211521), and [How to track importRange](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/220770464).

Comment: Since this is the case, I recommend either submitting a **Help** > **Help Sheets improve** on a spreadsheet or a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new), as those are the best ways to tell Google about these kinds of things.

Comment: @Saddles, thanks very much for all that digging. Now we can add this post to the pile I guess. I submitted a feature request via the Help Sheets improve menu and cross my fingers.